# Comment-based Help and parameter args[]

Tags: powershell, args

I have a PS script which is called from a Windows shortcut :

`C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file C:\applis\Batch\myScript.ps1`

It works fine and I can call my script by dropping multiple files on the shorcut.

However, as there is no explicit parameter name, what must I put in the comment to explain users the can call my script with multiple files and get this explanation with `Get-Help` ?

Thanks !

EDIT :
I found the solution thru an other question I asked.
Here is my new parameter block :

```
param (
    [switch] $CreateShortcut,
    [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
    [string[]] $FilesOrFolders
)
```

And then :

```
<#
  .SYNOPSIS
  ABCDE

  .DESCRIPTION
  ABCDE

  .PARAMETER CreateShortcut
  ABCDE

  .PARAMETER Files
  ABCDE
#>
```

In fact, I didn't know how to name the remaining parameters such as it appears in the comment-based help.

Comment: Please copy and paste, as text, the help and param() block into the question. See also https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-do-i-add-help-information-for-windows-powershell-parameters/